# How to setup secure tunnel to allow a client to communicate to a websocket?

Tags: ssl, websocket, tunnel, stunnel

I need to allow client to connect to a websocket on server 10.0.4.160. The 10.0.4.160 server does not have SSL installed on it but it have a websocket that is running on port 8080.

I need to setup a secure tunnel to allow the client to connect to the websocket.

I installed the stunnel on my windows Server 2008 R2, And changed my stunnel.conf file to look loke this

```
[websockets]
accept = 8443
connect = 8080
verify = 2
CAfile = ca-certs.pem
client = yes
```

I am expecting to connect to the server on port 8433 and the stunnel will allow the connection to connect to port 8080

This is the code that I use in the client's console "Of course, the console is on a PC that is on my internal network"

```
var conn = new WebSocket('wss://10.0.4.160:8443');
conn.onopen = function(e) {
    console.log("Connection established!");
};

conn.onmessage = function(e) {
    console.log(e.data);
};
```

While on the server I open up a command line and I execute this
telnet localhost 8080

I get a command line and when I fire the code above from a console I see this in the server's command line

[image]

But few seconds later I get this error in the console

```
WebSocket connection to 'wss://10.0.4.160:8443/' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_TIMED_OUT
```

If I try to send a command using `conn.sent('Hello')` I get this error

```
VM289:2 Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'send' on 'WebSocket': Still in CONNECTING state.
    at Error (native)
    at <anonymous>:2:6
    at Object.InjectedScript._evaluateOn (<anonymous>:905:140)
    at Object.InjectedScript._evaluateAndWrap (<anonymous>:838:34)
    at Object.InjectedScript.evaluate (<anonymous>:694:21)
```

Additionally, I tried to turn on debugging in strunnel by adding `debug = 7`

This is what I got in the stunnel console. I don't understand what is wrong as the logs show that the client is connected but I can't send messages from the client to the server

```
2015.08.16 16:40:06 LOG7[36]: Service [websockets] started
2015.08.16 16:40:06 LOG5[36]: Service [websockets] accepted connection from 10.0.4.195:21963
2015.08.16 16:40:06 LOG6[36]: s_connect: connecting 127.0.0.1:8080
2015.08.16 16:40:06 LOG7[36]: s_connect: s_poll_wait 127.0.0.1:8080: waiting 10 seconds
2015.08.16 16:40:06 LOG5[36]: s_connect: connected 127.0.0.1:8080
2015.08.16 16:40:06 LOG5[36]: Service [websockets] connected remote server from 127.0.0.1:50891
2015.08.16 16:40:06 LOG7[36]: Remote socket (FD=668) initialized
2015.08.16 16:40:06 LOG6[36]: SNI: sending servername: localhost
2015.08.16 16:40:06 LOG7[36]: SSL state (connect): before/connect initialization
2015.08.16 16:40:06 LOG7[36]: SSL state (connect): SSLv2/v3 write client hello A
```

What am I doing wrong here? 
How come the connection keeps failing?